# Disable scroll in UIScrollView while multi touching

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, multi-touch

In my program I use two fingers to pinch (zoom in and out), so sometimes when I want to pinch, app scrolls. 
I would like to don't let scrolling in UIScrollView while two or more touches are on screen. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIGestureRecognizer`.
In you case you must use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, with 2 finger and one tap.
Attach the gesture on the table view.